# mongodb elemmatch on multiple columns facing issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2a1a48131a2116cca581d6"),
    "a" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"
        }
    ],
    "b" : [],
    "c" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"
        }
    ],
    "parentpost_id" : "5b2a1a48131a2116cca581d5",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I would like to do query for all element i.e a, b & c columns have userid exits or not through elementmatch.

I know elemmatch query for single column i.e

```
db.CollectionName.find({'parentpost_id': ObjectId('5b2a1a48131a2116cca581d5')}, {a: {$elemMatch: {'userid': '5b28c9447228da1230963d4c' }}}, function(err, response) {
if (err) {
 console.log(err);
} else {
 console.log(response)
}
```

But i don't know how to do query for column a, column b and column c on one single query. Is there anyone who guide me. Any help is really appreciated.

//I used the approach for multiple but it will return blank array.

```
db.CollectionName.find({
'parentpost_id': ObjectId('5b2a1a48131a2116cca581d5'),
$and: [
        {'likes': {'$elemMatch': {'userid': req.body.userid } } },
        {'ratings': {'$elemMatch': {'userid': req.body.userid } } },
        {'retweets': {'$elemMatch': {'userid': req.body.userid } } },
      ]
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection

Comment: Dude its not relevant what you are suggested. I want multiple columns elemmatch on single query

Comment: Make it clear what you are asking - how to search documents like in the last snippet, or how to project fields like in the previous one. Also edit the last snippet. It is incomplete and fields don't agree with previous code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator and  [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator simultaneously this way

```
db.collection.find({
  "parentpost_id": "5b2a1a48131a2116cca581d5",
  "a": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "userid": "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "userid": "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"
    }
  },
  "c": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "userid": "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The page you are referring to clearly states there is no need to use $elementMatch in this particular case: *If you specify only a single <query> condition in the $elemMatch expression, you do not need to use $elemMatch.* As a side note, there is no need for explicit $and either.

Comment: You are right that there is no need to use `$and` here but to use `$elemMatch` is the best way to match the condition inside the array of objects

Comment: Elaborate please. `{"a": {"$elemMatch": {"userid": "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"}}},` is better than `{"a.userid": "5b28c9447228da1230963d4c"}` only if you measure it by number of characters in the query.

Comment: Ok... See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JYshLsiCNOD)... Can you do this query without using `$elemMatch` and only in find query?

Comment: **only a single <query> condition** is a crucial bit. You have 2 conditions in your "here" example, and it is exactly the case for $elemMatch. In the answer you have 1 condition, so there is no need to use it.

Comment: Yes that's why I am asking to use `$elemMatch` every time whether it is single query condition or multiple... Use of `$elemMatch` is a good way to drill into an array... It's my way of thinking rest I don't know...

Comment: Fair enough, I don't say it doesn't work, but the word choice of the answer misleads. "You need to use" implies it is mandatory, which is not, and opposes to the documentation you are referring to.